# OpenID Architecture for Java

Tags: java, openid

I'm trying to understand the concept and benefits of implementing OpenID in your project. And, since I'm a Java developer, I'm more or less equally interested in understanding its main Java implementation, `openid4java`.

My understanding is that OpenID is a standard for provisioning decentralized IDs in a uniform way. Now, if that is totally (or even slightly) incorrect, please correct me!

Assuming I'm still on track, I see that all sorts or organizations have been using OpenID, such as MySpace, who identifies each of their users with a URL matching `http://www.myspace.com/username`.

So how does OpenID work as a system? Does it just manifest itself as a network of "OpenID Servers" that, like DNS machines, coordinate and make sure all IDs in their system are unique and match a certain pattern? Or, is it just an algorithm to be used which, like `GUID`, produces globally-unique IDs for each client domain (such as MySpace).

I'm just not understanding how OpenID actually manifests itself, and how frameworks like openid4java ineract with that "manifestation". (What their uses are).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there are two sides of the OpenID communication - the provider and the consumer. The consumer is the application that tries to authenticate using OpenID, and the provider is the server to which the authentication request is sent.

Each provider has a so-called Endpoint - url that accepts authentication requests. You should know that URL in advance when supporting an OpenID provider. First you have to discover what is the endpoint for a given openId, and then exchange messages with that provider. This is all wrapped in openid4java `ConsumerManager`.

Then happens the authentication - you redirect the user to a provider url, where the user confirms he wants to login using his account (should be logged in), then the provider redirects back to you, and then you can get the requested information about the user (through another request)

Comment: Thanks @Bozho! So how would something like openid4java work with an SSO framework like OpenSSO? What's the "division of labor" there?

Comment: to be honest - I don't know :)

Comment: Found [this](http://www.alleged.org.uk/pdc/2007/08/13.html) article, which would probably make sense to developers who have already had experience with either SSO and/or OpenID. To me, it doesn't make a whole bunch of sense, but I'll save that for another research effort ;-) ~ thanks again for your answer